# Installing ubuntu on a new computer?

Tags: installation

Can I install ubuntu on a brand new computer with all new parts including hard drive? Or must i have Windows or Mac OS installed first before installing ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You only need a Ubuntu installation CD/DVD/USB to do it. You can run Ubuntu as an OS. You don't need Windows or Mac OS X at all.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need another OS installed first to install Ubuntu.  You just need to boot from the LiveCD or LiveUSB and select **Install**.

The only thing that you might want to check is the [Component catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/) of hardware certified to work on Ubuntu to see if all your components will work correctly.  A  component missing does not necessarily mean that it will not work , it may have not been tested yet.  If unsure just **Try Ubuntu** from the LiveCD/USB to see if it works.

If you have an external graphics card, they can sometimes cause problems, usually these result in a black screen either during boot form the LiveCD or after installation.  These can usually be fixed by installing the graphic drivers needed with the **Additional Drivers** program in Ubuntu.  If you get the black screen a great detailed answer on how to fix it is here:
[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Good instructions to install the drivers that may be needed to fix the graphics after you can boot/install Ubuntu is here:
[How do I install extra drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/a/47511/65969)